# how to give effetcts to an image like in instagram

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5

hi  there I’m new to iPhone development. i have created an iPhone app  that can post images like in Facebook. In that one i would like to include an option to edit that images with different effects like in Instagram. Any one can help in this pleas provide a sample project or code if it possible.

**-Thanks in advance**

Comment: You would need to specify witch effect do you have in mind, and don't expect that all code would be posted just for copy and paste.

Comment: no need of all codes. just need some filtering effects like in instagram.  - thanks for your reply

Comment: And how do you suppose that those filter work? They are code and code request are frowned upon also asking for libraries and other offsite resource are off-topic for stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad larson's [GPUImage project](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) has various filters that you would like to apply. There is also a sample project in there which shows how to do it. You will have check it and modify it as per your needs . Hope this helps you in achieving what you want to implement.

Comment: You can accept the answer by checking the tickmark , if it helped you :)